# CSS footer not working properly in every dimensions

Tags: css, footer

Im trying to create a responsive footer. The only problem I have so far is that in different screen sizes the footer background color kind of disappears. In smaller screens the footer background color appears correctly, in large screens it only shows like 50px.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22Quu/

And here's the two images that exemplifies what I'm talking about.

The first image is how it looks in smaller screens and how it should always looks. As you can see the background color fits in every element.
[image]

The second image is shown in larger screens.
[image]

As you can see, the background color of the footer does not fit in the whole object.
I thought, at first, that the problem could be somehow related with `media screen`, but it isn't.

Btw, I'm adapting this original footer http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/374/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/22Quu/2/)

Add:

`overflow: hidden;`

to `._footer`

This will contain the floated elements which are pushing content outside the element, forcing it to expand with them.

Answer (score 2):

As you have give `float: left` to `<li>` you need to clear it or add `overflow: hidden` to `._footer > ul`

```
    <footer class="_footer">    
    <ul>
<li><!--your content--></li>
<li><!--your content--></li>
<li><!--your content--></li>
<li class="clear" ></li>
    </ul>
    </footer>
```

CSS for clear class

```
._footer > ul li.clear {
float:none;
clear: both;
width: auto;
padding: 0;
}
```